# How to avoid that a javascript set cookie function is overriding/deleting previous cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm building a function in Javascript to `setCookie` and I have this issue, when I try to `setCookie` in the same file for 2 cookies, the second call to set cookie deletes the first `setCookie` values.

My `setCookie` function

```
import { serialize } from 'cookie';

export default function setCookie(res, name, value, options = {}) {
  console.log('SET COOKIE', name, value); 
  const stringValue =
    typeof value === 'object' ? 'j:' + JSON.stringify(value) : String(value);

  if ('maxAge' in options) {
    options.expires = new Date(Date.now() + options.maxAge);
    options.maxAge /= 1000;
  }

  console.log(stringValue);

  res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', serialize(name, String(stringValue), options));
}
```

And the `setCookie` is used in the following method as

```
setCookie(res, 'conversationId', conversation.id, {
          path: '/api',
          httpOnly: true,
        });
    
setCookie(res, 'memberId', member.id, {
          path: '/api',
          httpOnly: true,
        });
```

The first setCookie is not showing in browser cookies but the second yes.
I don't see the `conversationId` but only `memberId`.
Seems the second call deletes the first one.

Full method

```
const getHandler = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const recipientIds = parseRecipientIds(req.cookies.recipientIds);
    const documentId = req.query.id;

    const doc = await getIcfDocument(documentId);
    if (!doc) {
      log.warn('Document %s could not be retrieved', documentId);
      return res
        .status(400)
        .json({ message: 'Document could not be retrieved' });
    }

    // TODO some docs don't have recipients?
    const recipient = doc.Consentee.recipients.find((x) =>
      recipientIds.includes(x.id)
    );

    await addActivity({
      activityTypes: ['recipient_link_opened'],
      activityOwnerType: 'DOCUMENT',
      activityOwnerId: documentId,
      documentId,
      metadata: {
        recipientId: recipient?.id,
      },
    });

    const { conversation, member } = await joinConsentConversation(
      doc,
      recipient
    );
    if (!conversation) {
      log.warn('Recipient %o could not join conversation', recipient);
      return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Could not join conversation' });
    }

    console.log('CONVERSATION HERE...', conversation);

    const consenteeData = {
      document: doc,
      conversation,
      recipientId: recipient.id,
    };

    console.log(member.id, conversation.id);

    setCookie(res, 'conversationId', conversation.id, {
      path: '/api',
      httpOnly: true,
    });

    setCookie(res, 'memberId', member.id, {
      path: '/api',
      httpOnly: true,
    });

    log.info('Recipient %s document %s logged in', recipient.id, doc.id);
    return res.status(200).json(consenteeData);
  } catch (err) {
    log.error('handle form %s', err.message);
    return res.status(500).json(res.data?.errors);
  }
};
```

As extra information when I do the `console.log(...)` in the methods function this is the result

```
CONVERSATION HERE... { id: '17', status: 'EMPTY', messages: { nodes: [] } }
21 17
SET COOKIE conversationId 17
17
SET COOKIE memberId 21
21
```

When I check the cookies in the browser I don't see the `17` which corresponds to the `conversation.id`. That value is not set in cookies and I have no idea why.

Comment: What does your `serialize` function do? Please post its definition.

Comment: This looks like NodeJS code, not web-browser clients script. Please clarify where and how this code is being used.

Comment: _"How to avoid..."_ - Add the new value to the current cookie value instead of simply overwriting it. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: The `serialize` comes from this pkg https://github.com/jshttp/cookie#readme so please check that for it's definition @Dai

Comment: Can you explain how to do that @Andreas

Comment: I did a research of hours about and follow some guides but cannot find a solution so I did an effort to search online if you know a link explaining this can you shared please @Andreas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's actually correct behaviour, as you're *setting* a value, and not appending one to the headers.

From the [NodeJS documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_setheader_name_value):

> If this header already exists in the to-be-sent headers, its value will be replaced. Use an array of strings here to send multiple headers with the same name.

The solution is, therefore, right there in the documentation.

Change the following line in your `setCookie` function:

```
res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', serialize(name, String(stringValue), options));
```

to:

```
let cookieValues = res.getHeader('set-cookie') || [];
if (typeof cookieValues === 'string') {
  cookieValues = [cookieValues];
}
cookieValues.push(serialize(name, String(stringValue), options));
res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', cookieValues);
```

Comment: Thank you  that was really perfect